# Good reference for co-groups, perspective of co-algebra applications

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, computer-science

There are lot of applications of state transition systems STS (computer science, planning problems in robotics and so on) and lot of algorithms are devised, but the mathematical background for STS is only emerging. It seems that the coalgebra is the most beautiful theory so far, see, e.g. for the fundamental works, tutorials and reviews by J. J. M. M. Rutten (many of the are freely available). But I am taken aback by the writing of the mentioned J. J. M. M. Rutten: 
"Deep insights about groups are not obtained by studying universal algebra. Nor
will universal coalgebra lead to dicult theorems about (specic types of) systems.
Like universal algebra, its possible merit consists of the fact that it \: : : tidies up
a mass of rather trivial detail, allowing us to concentrate our powers on the hard
core of the problem".

And after some months of studies I am starting to believe this quotation. But what should be the path forward? In classical case the abstract notions of algebra can be more elaborated by the studies of groups and the especially the group representation have a lot of practical applications (e.g. they form the theory of special functions, the characters of irreducible representations form the solutions to the eigenvalue problems and so on, so on). So - can the analogy between algebras and co-algebras be continued to the case of groups and co-groups? Is there some work already done? Are there some hints that such path forward can yield results?

The literature of co-groups ir really scarce, but maybe there is some good trends, especially for applications?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Can you please make the question more precise and focussed? Probably I won't be able to answer, but I would like to understand the other answers (hopefully there will be some of them) or what they are talking about ;).

Comment: The question is - are there some good books, articles on the co-groups and the representation theory of co-groups? The only book I have found is "Cogroups and Co-rings in Categories of Associative Rings" and there are only some articles. Maybe there is something more (in the deep web, it exists, Google is not findin everyting). Maybe some mentoring is available - what are the open problems and is co-groups worth to research.